# Как объединить фреймы, чтобы они следовали друг за другом?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Как объединить 3-4 фрейма так, чтобы они следовали друг за другом? То есть, сначала шел первый, за ним в новые столбцы склеивался второй, потом третий и т.д.

Пример:

Вход:

df1

```
a b c 
1 3 7
2 3 4
3 3 7
```

df2

```
k d h 
0 3 1
2 0 4
3 3 7
```

df3

```
o p r 
0 3 1
1 0 1
1 3 1
```

Выход: df4

```
a b c k d h o p r 
1 3 7 0 3 1 0 3 1
2 3 4 2 0 4 1 0 1
3 3 7 3 3 7 1 3 1
```

Опробованные функции объединяют как бы сверху вниз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Параметр `axis` указывает по какой оси вы хотите объединять данные - вертикально или горизонтально.

```
df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)

In [167]: df4
Out[167]:
   a  b  c  k  d  h  o  p  r
0  1  3  7  0  3  1  0  3  1
1  2  3  4  2  0  4  1  0  1
2  3  3  7  3  3  7  1  3  1
```